# how to applied text from for loop out value to regex

Tags: jquery, regex, string, match

In my regex function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    str1 = $('#text').val();  
 var matched = str1.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
          var addy="";
    for(i=0; i<matched.length; i++)
    {
      addy +='/'+matched[i]+'/g<br>';        
    }
     var ex = str1.match(new RegExp(addy));
    $('#demo').html('matched value:'+addy);//regexp terms are correctly outed.
    $('#demo1').html('for loop out to reg:'+ex);//null value are present
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="-5x-7y+2y-7h-9t">
<button>go</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

applied the value to regex from for loop outed text.regex function correctly out with for loop.but applied this result to another regex function null value present.i need just like append function when appiled all for loop fnction .Please tell what is the reason & how to solve my problem.thnks

Comment: It looks like your building a regex string like `/something/g<br>/somethingelse/g<br>`.  I don't believe that is valid.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I trying to auto detect the value from input text also separate the variables A-Z.And separately add the each same variables value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($){
  var $text = $('#text');
  var regex = /[+-/*][a-zA-Z0-9]+/g
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){
    console.log($text.val().match(regex));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" value="-5x-7y+2y-7h-9t">
<button>go</button>
```

Are you trying to break apart the expression pieces?  If so you could do something like the following.

Comment: where is the output?

Comment: It's in the console.  Are you unfamiliar with the console?  Right click the page and choose to inspect element.  This will bring up your browser dev tools, one of the tabs being the console.  Just in case your unfamiliar with some of the basics: http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide1

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/bv4w5eoe/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    str1 = $('#text').val();  
 var matched = str1.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
          var addy="/";
    for(i=0; i<matched.length; i++)
    {
      addy += matched[i]+'|';        
    }
    addy = addy.slice(0, -1);
    addy += '/g'
    debugger;
     var ex = str1.match(new RegExp(addy));
    $('#demo').html('matched value:'+addy);//regexp terms are correctly outed.
    $('#demo1').html('for loop out to reg:'+ex);//null value are present
  });
  });
```